# Passing PHP variables to jQuery integer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

basically I know more or less how to do it but would like to know if there is any better way?

I have the following variables in PHP

```
$day; $month; $year;
```

The ones above have values from exploding a php date string.

Below is PHP plugin function which states the date for countdown.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();   
    austDay = new Date(2013, 12, 22);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
});
</script>
```

I would like to pass the date day/month/year variables into that function from PHP
how can I do it, when I tried to attach  to the javavariable and put that variable in place of the date part, it didnt work.

Thanks for all help

Comment: Do it the same way you'd insert any other PHP variable into the HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var day  = <?php echo $day ?>; 
var month = <?php echo $month ?>; 
var year = <?php echo $year ?>;

$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();   
    austDay = new Date( year, month, day );
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
});
```

Comment: Yep, been doing this way shows 0,0,0 when touching the year value inside new Date()

Comment: What do you mean when "touching" the year value inside new Date() ?

Comment: OK every solution works! Thank you. I have gone through the code one more time and corrected one variable, as it was getting the start date, not end date, therefore it was showing 0,0,0.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways you could skin this.

- Fetch the values via $.ajax with php returning the values as a jsonified array (echo json_encode($my_values))
- If the page generating the html is a php page then just new Date();
- Place the values into hidden form fields anywhere on the page or into data-day, data-month, data-year attributes of a relevant object on the page and fetch the values using jquery

  - day = $('#hiddenfield_day').val(); //put the var day into the day field of new date, etc

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
austDay = new Date(<?= $year ?>, <?= $month ?> , <?= $day ?>);
```

That said, keep in mind that Javascript's [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) month param takes a number in the 0 - 11 range.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly how I have been doing it, but it shows 0,0,0 when I touch the "YEAR" value, the month and day can be set with <?php  echo ""; ?>

Comment: OK every solution works! Thank you. I have gone through the code one more time and corrected one variable, as it was getting the start date, not end date, therefore it was showing 0,0,0.